# AWS create bucket failing, what is the issue?

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

Getting this error:

```
S3 err creating bucket: operation error S3: CreateBucket, https response error StatusCode: 0, RequestID: , HostID: , request send failed, Put "https://s3..amazonaws.com/astromail-test3.com": dial tcp: lookup s3..amazonaws.com: no such host. With bucket name: astromail-test3.com
```

When I switch my credential to default it works correctly and creates the bucket. But, when I use my custom IAM it is not working, but the error is not a permission error. What is going on? I have set the right permission I believe and if that was the issue usually sdks output a permission denied with required permission which you can then update. Here it is just failing with the above output.

```
package smtpstack

import (
    "AstroMail/storage"
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
    "strings"

    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/aws"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/config"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/s3"
)

// MakeAWSS3BucketNameCompliant makes a string compliant with AWS S3 bucket naming rules
func makeAWSS3BucketNameCompliant(input string) string {
    // Convert the input string to lowercase
    input = strings.ToLower(input)

    // Replace invalid characters with "-"
    invalidCharsRegex := regexp.MustCompile(`[^a-z0-9-.]`)
    input = invalidCharsRegex.ReplaceAllString(input, "-")

    // Replace multiple consecutive "-" with single "-"
    input = strings.ReplaceAll(input, "--", "-")

    // input = strings.ReplaceAll(input, ".", "-")

    // Remove leading and trailing "-"
    input = strings.Trim(input, "-")

    // Limit the length to 63 characters
    if len(input) > 63 {
        input = input[:63]
    }

    return input
}

func CreateEmailBucket(domain string) error {
    bucketName := makeAWSS3BucketNameCompliant(fmt.Sprintf("AstroMail-%s", domain))

    sdkConfig, err := config.LoadDefaultConfig(context.TODO(), config.WithSharedConfigProfile("AstroMailApp"))

    fmt.Println(sdkConfig, err, bucketName)

    S3Client := s3.NewFromConfig(sdkConfig)

    newBucket, err := S3Client.CreateBucket(context.TODO(), &s3.CreateBucketInput{
        Bucket: aws.String(bucketName),
    })

    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("S3 err creating bucket: %s. With bucket name: %s", err, bucketName)
    }

    fmt.Println("new bucket: ", newBucket)

    storage.SaveKey("bucketName", bucketName)
    return nil
}
```

Comment: The fact that `s3..amazonaws.com` appears in the error message suggests you might have mis-configured your region as empty string.

Comment: but why does it work when I use another credential? Shouldn't that be an issue regardless of the iam account?

Comment: The default region name is a per-profile setting.

Comment: nice catch I wiil post it as a solution. You are correct. I don't understand how it is attaching it to the profile but I have found a way to set it during execution.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution, the key part is adding this config.WithRegion("us-east-1") to the sdkConfig variable intialization. Here is the full code I made some more changes like waiting for the bucket to be created.

```
func CreateEmailBucket(domain string) error {
    bucketName := makeAWSS3BucketNameCompliant(fmt.Sprintf("AstroMail-%s", domain))

    sdkConfig, err := config.LoadDefaultConfig(context.TODO(), config.WithSharedConfigProfile("AstroMailApp"), s)

    fmt.Println(sdkConfig, err, bucketName)

    s3Client := s3.NewFromConfig(sdkConfig)

    createBucketParams := &s3.CreateBucketInput{
        Bucket: aws.String(bucketName),
    }

    _, err = s3Client.CreateBucket(context.TODO(), createBucketParams)

    if err != nil {
        panic(fmt.Errorf("failed to create bucket: %v", err))
    }

    // Wait for S3 Bucket to Exist
    fmt.Println("wait for s3 bucket to exist")
    waiter := s3.NewBucketExistsWaiter(s3Client)
    err = waiter.Wait(context.TODO(), &s3.HeadBucketInput{
        Bucket: aws.String(bucketName),
    }, 120*time.Second)

    if err != nil {
        panic(fmt.Sprintf("bucket failed to materialize: %v", err))
    }

    storage.SaveKey("bucketName", bucketName)
    return nil
}
```

The wait for the bucket to create just waits a set time which I don't think is smart since it is created faster most of the time. I am going to make it loop and check multiple times instead. Thanks people who commented.